# Javascript functions not working when called

Tags: javascript

I defined 2 javascript functions in a php file

```
<script type="javascript">
function inviaRichiesta(){
    //some data elaborations
    location.href = '../index.php'; //page redirect       
}

function caricaDati(){
    var ele = document.getElementById("int").options[document.getElementById("int").selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("tip").value = <?php echo $_SESSION['caricato']['tipologia']; ?>
}
</script>
```

but none of them seems to work when i change the value inside the select menu

```
  <select name="intervento" onchange="inviaRichiesta()" id="int">
```

what i need is to redirect the browser to a page when a choise in the select menu is made. any clue?

Console output:

```
> [12:09:07.771] ReferenceError: inviaRichiesta is not defined @
> http://localhost/tirocinio/view/inserimento_dati_intervento.php:1
```

Comment: OMFG: `document.getElementById("int").options[document.getElementById("int").selectedIndex].text` My eyes...

Comment: I'd recommend using `json_encode` for exporting variables to JavaScript. Currently have no escaping function, you're probably getting a syntax error.

Comment: so what is the error outputted on the js console?

Comment: If `$_SESSION['caricato']['tipologia']` is a string then you need to quote it. `value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['caricato']['tipologia']; ?>";`

Comment: @jcubic no! `json_encode`! If the value is `Look! a quote: "` you're setting getting a syntax error. `json_encode` takes care of this.

Comment: forgetting the quotes `document.getElementById("tip").value = '<?php echo $_SESSION['caricato']['tipologia']; ?>';`  quotes?

Comment: If you change the location href to `'../index.php'`, you're telling the browser to go to `http://../index.php`. It should be an absolute url

Comment: try this in your function inviaRichiesta(){ window.location = "../index.php"; }

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you right json_encode is always best option.

Comment: This is the output of console:
[12:09:07.771] ReferenceError: inviaRichiesta is not defined @ http://localhost/tirocinio/view/inserimento_dati_intervento.php:1

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

For redirecting to some other page you should not use **location.href** you should use "window.location". Just replace and try.

You can try this as well,

> **onchange="window.location='../index.php'"**

**location.href** - The href property returns the entire URL of the current page.

**window.location** - The window.location object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score -1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/dv89z/1/)

on change page is redirected to URL

```
window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Comment: ungh.... can't you redirect to a site that's actually useful? More importantly, the content of the redirect function isn't what's failing.